# Remove escaping for Unicode codes

Tags: javascript, unicode

I have a string with at least one occurrence of Unicode codes. The string looks something like this `var unicodeIsMean = "\\u0026";`.

Which is the easiest way of converting this into `\u0026` (which I can then turn into `&`). I tried replacing `\\u` with `\u`, but it doesn't work. The simplest way so far is to straight up do `string.replace("\\u0026", "&")`, but I can't do this for all codes, since I'm not sure how many characters will be escaped this way.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the escape?  IE `string.replace("\\\\u", "\\u")` ?

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse` might help:

```
var unicodeIsMean = "\\u0026";
var decoded = JSON.parse(`{"str": "${unicodeIsMean}"}`).str;
console.log(decoded);
```